# Truncate continued fractions

Tags: code-golf, math, rational-numbers

Related: [Cleaning up decimal numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/207352/78410)

### Background

A **[continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction)** is a way to represent a real number as a sequence of integers in the following sense:

$$
x = a_0 + \cfrac{1}{a_1 + \cfrac{1}{a_2 + \cfrac{1}{\ddots + \cfrac{1}{a_n}}}} = [a_0; a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n]
$$

Finite continued fractions represent rational numbers; infinite continued fractions represent irrational numbers. This challenge will focus on finite ones for the sake of simplicity.

Let's take \$\frac{277}{642}\$ as an example. It has the following continued fraction:

$$
\frac{277}{642} =
0 + \cfrac{1}{2 + \cfrac{1}{3 + \cfrac{1}{6 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{3 + \cfrac{1}{3}}}}}} =  [0;2, 3, 6, 1, 3, 3]
$$

If we truncate the continued fraction at various places, we get various *approximations* of the number \$\frac{277}{642}\$:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
 \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{Continued Fraction}} & \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{Fraction}}
& \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{Decimal}} & \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{Relative error}}\\\hline
 [0] & 0/1 & 0.0\dots & 1 \\\hline
 [0;2] & 1/2 & 0.50\dots & 0.15 \\\hline
 [0;2,3] & 3/7 & 0.428\dots & 0.0067 \\\hline
 [0;2,3,6] & 19/44 & 0.4318\dots & 0.00082 \\\hline
 [0;2,3,6,1] & 22/51 & 0.43137\dots & 0.00021 \\\hline
 [0;2,3,6,1,3] & 85/197 & 0.431472\dots & 0.000018 \\\hline
 [0;2,3,6,1,3,3] & 277/642 & 0.4314641\dots & 0
\end{array}
$$

These are called *convergents* of the given number. In fact, the convergents are the *best approximations* among all fractions with the same or lower denominator. This property was used in [a proposed machine number system of rational numbers](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel5/12/35241/01676511.pdf) to find the approximation that fits in a machine word of certain number of bits.

(There are some [subtle points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_approximations) around "best approximation", but we will ignore it and just use the convergents. As a consequence, if your language/library has a "best rational approximation" built-in, it is unlikely to correctly solve the following task.)

### Task

Given a rational number \$r\$ given as a finite continued fraction and a positive integer \$D\$, find the best approximation of \$r\$ among its convergents so that its denominator does not exceed \$D\$.

The continued fraction is guaranteed to be a finite sequence of integers, where the first number is non-negative, and the rest are strictly positive. You may output the result as a built-in rational number or two separate integers. The output fraction does not need to be reduced.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
[0, 2, 3, 6, 1, 3, 3], 43 => 3/7
[0, 2, 3, 6, 1, 3, 3], 44 => 19/44
[5, 6, 7], 99 => 222/43
```

Comment: I've edited the Mathjax slightly to use [\cfrac](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tex_commands/cfrac.htm), the recommended usage for continued fractions

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>72 68</s>   67 bytes

Expects `(max_denominator)(seq)`. Returns `[numerator, denominator]`.

```javascript
m=>g=([v,...a],n=0,d=1,N=1,D=0)=>(d+=D*v)<=m?g(a,N,D,N*v+n,d):[N,D]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fctBDoIwEAXQvafosoWRQlslGAc3rLkAYdFQIBqgRkyvXysrw8JJfjI/@e@hnV671/35Pi7W9H5AP2M5Im0cJEmiW1gwBYMZ1CEVpgxLamKsIseuON9GqqGGCurIxQsYdmlCa31nl9VOfTLZkQ5USUabFIgAIoGcgWTbI1vGCOdE8vywA@ovyAqu1I4URSCnbZx/Z78XiBCCK@k/)

#### Commented

```javascript
m =>             // outer function taking m = maximum denominator
g = (            // inner recursive function taking:
  [v,            //   v = next term from the continued fraction
      ...a],     //   a[] = remaining terms
  n = 0,         //   n = previous numerator
  d = 1,         //   d = previous denominator
  N = 1,         //   N = current numerator
  D = 0          //   D = current denominator
) =>             //
  (d += D * v)   // we compute the new denominator d = D * v + d
                 // this results in NaN if v is undefined,
                 // which forces the comparison to fail
  <= m ?         // if it's less than or equal to m:
    g(           //   do a recursive call:
      a,         //     pass the remaining terms of the continued fraction
      N, D,      //     pass the current numerator and denominator
      N * v + n, //     pass the new numerator
      d          //     pass the new denominator
    )            //   end of recursive call
  :              // else:
    [N, D]       //   we're done: return [N, D]
```

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>25</sup> 23 bytes

```
(]{:@#~0#.>:)2 x:(+%)/\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NWKrrRyU6wyU9eysNI0UKqw0tFU19WP@a3KlJmfkKxgrmCvoWimYGCukKRjoKBjpKBjrKJjpKBiCGcYVEFVGRkYgJUCFlpZAhaZgJeZQSUNLBRMTsCEmOAz5DwA)

<sup>-2 thanks to Bubbler</sup>

### how

We'll use `43 f 0, 2, 3, 6, 1, 3, 3x` as an example...

- `(+%)/\` For each prefix `\`, reduce from the right `/` using the J hook `(+%)`, which adds its left arg to the inverse of its right argument.  This returns rational numbers:

  ```
  0 1r2 3r7 19r44 22r51 85r197 277r642
  ```
- `2 x:` Convert to pairs:

  ```
  0   1
  1   2
  3   7
  19  44
  22  51
  85  197
  277 642
  ```
- `]...#~...` Filter that list for valid denominators with the following mask:

  - `>:` Is each number less than or equal to the left arg:

    ```
    1 1
    1 1
    1 1
    1 0
    1 0
    0 0
    0 0
    ```
  - `0#.` Convert to a "base 0" number.  This will be `1` only for pairs whose 2nd element (denominator) is `1`:

    ```
    1 1 1 0 0 0 0
    ```
- Our filtered list becomes:

  ```
  0   1
  1   2
  3   7
  ```
- `{:@` Return the last element.

Comment: `2|&#.` can be `0#.`.

Comment: @Bubbler Ha!  I love it.

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 47 bytes

```
Last@*Cases[a_/;Denominator@a<=#]@*Convergents&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73yexuMRByzmxOLU4OjFe39olNS8/NzMvsSS/yCHRxlY5FiiZn1eWWpSemldSrPY/oCgzryRaWdcuLVo5OtooNjbWAUgbAmm1uuDkxLy6aq7qagMdBSMdBWMdBTMdBUMww7hWR8EESOCWNAFLmoKFzYEClpa1XLX/AQ)

-25 bytes from @att

Comment: [47 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73yexuMRByzmxOLU4OjFe39olNS8/NzMvsSS/yCHRxlY5FiiZn1eWWpSemldSrPY/oCgzryRaWdcuLVo5OtooNjbWAUgbAmm1uuDkxLy6aq7qagMdBSMdBWMdBTMdBUMww7hWR8EESOCWNAFLmoKFzYEClpa1XLX/AQ) taking `[D][r]` (`FromContinuedFraction` isn't necessary)

Answer (score 3):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╪£pÇUßi⌂Ω♫M⌂░◘
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=d89c708055e1697fea0e4d7fb008&i=43,+%5B0,+2,+3,+6,+1,+3,+3%5D%0A%0A44,+%5B0,+2,+3,+6,+1,+3,+3%5D%0A%0A99,+%5B5,+6,+7%5D%0A&m=1)

takes inputs as `<max denominator>,<continued fraction>`.

### Explanation

```
|[{r{su+km{Rn^<oH
|[{      m        for each prefix of the continued fraction
   r               reverse
    {   k          reduce by:
     su+            swap, reciprocal and add
          {    o  order by:
           R       denominator
            n^<    lesser than 2nd input + 1 ? 
                H last element
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 38 bytes

```
ＦＬθ«≔⟦§θι¹⟧ζＦ⮌…θι≔⁺⁺⊟ζ×ζκζζ¿¬›§ζ¹ηＰ⪫ζ/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY6xCsIwEIZn@xSH0wUiWisuTuIgioqIW3Eo9bTBmNgkFa347DHVuhwH//99d3mRmVxn0vuTNoArUmdXYMkYvKLO1FpxVphO3UId6YElB8E4xAcONZtEnS@yozsZSzh75pJmhb79asHQ4ltZ2XaEsA6CvbiSxZrDhbFG1erECXCjHc4NZY4M/s@GYhw6ReNcV9KJmxHK4VIL1WTdfpcF/O19mg44DDkkHMaB@S5JeHaUHHzvLj8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＦＬθ«
```

Loop over the prefixes.

```
≔⟦§θι¹⟧ζ
```

Form a "fraction" of the current element.

```
Ｆ⮌…θι
```

Loop over the preceding elements.

```
≔⁺⁺⊟ζ×ζκζζ
```

Invert the fraction and add on the element. This is some decidedly tricky coding. The old denominator is popped from the fraction, leaving behind the old numerator as a list of one element. This is vectorised multiplied by the element and added to the denominator, thus making a list of just the new numerator. The old numerator, still in its list, is then list concatenated to it, where it becomes the new denominator.

```
¿¬›§ζ¹ηＰ⪫ζ/
```

If the denominator is still small enough, overprint the previous fraction (if any) with the current fraction.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>88</s> 80 bytes

```r
function(x,y,`~`=cbind,z=1:0~0:1){for(i in x)z=z[,1]*i+z[,2]~z;z[,z[2,]<=y][,1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fclNCsIwFEbRuat4w0S/QX6q0tSspASKkUAmKZQKbaTZemxdgKN74Uw12Breyc9xTGzBiqEM1j9jeiFbaUQRRvJPGCcWKSZaeLa5h3TneNmrXMnd3twruIdd3UFbDcwzAVIgDbqB5G80BzWan/5oc@jV3EFty@sX)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 162 bytes

```python
lambda x,y:min((abs(q-g(*x)),q)for q in[g(*x[:i+1])for i in range(len(x))]if q.denominator<=y)[1]
g=lambda v,*k:v+Fraction(*k and(1,g(*k)))
from fractions import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY27DoJAEEV7v2LKGRyNiI9IpPUnkGIVFjfILKwbI1@PK7Gws5uce@6dbvA3K8mos/N4V@2lVPDiIW2NIKrLA/tFjdGLiHvS1kEPRvIPyVMzj4uJmcDAKakrvFeCQS6Mhn5ZVmLDjvLWHbOB8riY1dn3x5OjJn3OT05dvbGCUQNKSow5bDdENNPOtqC/8QNM21nno7FzRjxqzFcMa4aEYccQT0dSMGySUP3nbH6d7ZTuAz8ciMY3)

-28 bytes thanks to ovs

Comment: [179 bytes](https://tio.run/##hYzBroIwEEX3fsUspzgaEX1GIlt@AllUobwGmdLSGPh6LMaXvJ27yblnTj/5X8PJrLLr/JDdrZIw0pR2mrGwoIwDC5qLBqOxSPU6LsXCdGDgJDc1PmrGUYhSK7DbqmYTXqU37pJNJbX1lH2qNpW3Ae1mKQkhVs3f8KSoTZ/rHKMWJFcYU1DaRVHOdKCcvHtteADd9cZ5yD8A5AD53DvNHhUWO4I9QULwQxC/j6QkOCSh8805/HeO7/UU@PksxPwC) with a shorter `g` function.

Comment: [162 bytes](https://tio.run/##hY27DoJAEEV7v2LKGRyNiI9IpPUnkGIVFjfILKwbI1@PK7Gws5uce@6dbvA3K8mos/N4V@2lVPDiIW2NIKrLA/tFjdGLiHvS1kEPRvIPyVMzj4uJmcDAKakrvFeCQS6Mhn5ZVmLDjvLWHbOB8riY1dn3x5OjJn3OT05dvbGCUQNKSow5bDdENNPOtqC/8QNM21nno7FzRjxqzFcMa4aEYccQT0dSMGySUP3nbH6d7ZTuAz8ciMY3) by not using a key function and a shorter import.

Comment: @ovs Thanks for the golfs!

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <sup><s>70</s></sup> 69 bytes

```hs
x?m=last[y|y<-f x,y!!1<=m]
f(h:t)=[h,1]:[[a*h+b,a]|[a,b]<-f t]
f[]=[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5LboMwEED3nGISIYHLRBRDExExyQV6A8sLE0iwwk/gRZByd2pIqq66m3nvjTSVGu9lXc/z49xQrUYjpueU7a7wwGmziTJqpHP1q6NhJCqM5FEI9VEFOSr5FApzubTGNkKSkHOjdEtF5wD4GjuW7cZetX5IHnksc0@30nzrtrS6Lo1vzxn9BtJj@s0vWPzx0GNuMXQ9cOheHgbyh1IVrgqCrdyy82t7RzmzVT/o1rgDkVgUXHAtjNI1FNL65c1ZfCJwhBhhjxCtQywRkhjoBHF4cP4LkiWI0jBJHPG1yoPFabpgznmYxD8)

The relevant function is `(?)`, which takes as input the continued fraction `x` (as a list of integers) and the maximum denominator `m`. The output is a list of integers `[numerator,denominator]`.

### How?

```hs
x?m=            -- x=continued fraction, y=maximum denominator
  last[         -- return the last
    y|y<-f x,   --   convergent of x
    y!!1        --   whose denominator (i.e. second element)
      <=m       --     is at most m
  ]
```

```hs
f                   -- helper function for computing convergents
  (h:t)=            --   h=first number, t=rest of the continued fraction
    [h,1]:          --     the first convergent is h (i.e. h/1)
    [[a*h+b,a]      --     the other convergents are h+b/a (i.e. (a*h+b)/a)
      |[a,b]<-f t]  --       where a/b ranges over the convergents of t
f[]=[]              -- base case for the empty continued fraction
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 74 bytes

```
,
¶$%`,
¶
/1¶
+`\d+,(\d+)/(.+)
$.($2*_$1**)/$1
N$r`.*(\d+)
$1
L`.+¶(?!.+/)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvqhGcYP1fh@vQNhXVBBDFpW8IJLQTYlK0dTSAhKa@hp62JpeKnoaKkVa8iqGWlqa@iiGXn0pRgp4WWAEXkOuToKd9aJuGvaKetr7mf/cEvf8GOkY6xjpmOoZA0tjaxJgLTcCEyxTIMbe2tAQA) Takes the continued fraction and denominator on separate lines, but link includes test suite that splits on `;` for convenience. Explanation:

```
,
¶$%`,
```

Get all prefixes of the continued fraction.

```
¶
/1¶
```

Start each prefix with a denominator of 1.

```
+`\d+,(\d+)/(.+)
$.($2*_$1**)/$1
```

Calculate each resulting rational number from right to left.

```
N$r`.*(\d+)
$1
```

Sort the desired denominator into the list of rational numbers.

```
L`.+¶(?!.+/)
```

Output the rational number whose denominator is the largest that does not exceed the desired denominator.